# using async/await in a filter operation not waiting to finish after first await call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, filter, async-await

For a specific function, a list of tags (rfids) are required from a database, but various tables should be checked.

The issue is centered around the problem of a long running operation isn't `await`ed upon to finish before proceeding to the next.

**Problem:**

The code called below runs as follows (# numbers correspond to number in code below):

1. `getAllTags()` is called, starting the proc
2. `await db.dbRfid.findAll()` returns with X amount of valid results (not `Promise` objects)
3. start filtering call on valid objects & await finish (await place since some function calls inside are async calls.
4. call `const driverTags = await tag.getDrivers();`

At this point, one would expect this function to return the result and proceed to the next function i.e.

```
// #5
const truckTags = await tag.getTrucks();
```

What infact happens is for each of the `allTags` items, the `getDrivers()` gets called and the `filter()` exits and the code continues on by executing this next:

```
// #6
if (pureTags) {
    return filteredTags;
}
```

**Question:**

To my understanding, I am `await`ing `async` operations correctly, yet it seems like the filter only accepts/allows one `async` operation.

I assume I did something wrong, yet I am unable to the cause of the problem. Any advice would be appreciated!

**Full code implementation below:**

Called with e.g.

```
const listOfTags = await getAllTags();
```

Specific tag requirements (all valid, unused, enabled & unrevoked tags)

```
const listOfTags = await getAllTags(false, true, true, true);
```

Problem code:

```
// #1
const getAllTags = async (pureTags = false, unused = true, enabled = true, notRevoked = false) => {
    // #2
    let allTags = await db.dbRfid.findAll()
    // #3
    let filteredTags = await allTags.filter(async tag => {
        // check tag used
        if (unused) {
            // #4
            const driverTags = await tag.getDrivers();
            // #5
            const truckTags = await tag.getTrucks();
            const userTags = await tag.getUsers();
            if (driverTags.length > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (truckTags.length > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (userTags.length > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // check tag enabled
        if (enabled && !tag.enabled) {
            return false;
        }

        // check tag revoked or return true
        return notRevoked && !tag.revoked;
    });

    // return tags as is
    // #6
    if (pureTags) {
        return filteredTags;
    }

    return filteredTags.map(tag => {
        return {
            id: tag.id,
            rfid: tag.rfid,
            expiryDate: tag.expiryDate,
            revoked: tag.revoked,
            enabled: tag.enabled
        }
    });
}
```

---

**Update**

I should mention:

1. no 'errors' of any sort are shown to indicate of some problem.
2. the `.getDrivers()` is a getter created by [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html) which returns a promise.

---

**Update 2**

After comment by `evgeni fotia`

I originally had this code, however chose not to include it as it may havve complicated matters. However, this it the original code I attempted with the addition of the `await Promise.all()`.

```
const getAllTags = async (pureTags = false, unused = true, enabled = true, notRevoked = false) => {
    let allTags = await db.dbRfid.findAll()
    let filteredTags = await Promise.all(
        // await allTags.filter(async tag => {      //tried the await here too - for good measure
        allTags.filter(async tag => {
            // check tag used
            if (unused) {
                const driverTags = await tag.getDrivers();
                const truckTags = await tag.getTrucks();
                const userTags = await tag.getUsers();
                if (driverTags.length > 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (truckTags.length > 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (userTags.length > 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // check tag enabled
            if (enabled && !tag.enabled) {
                return false;
            }

            // check tag revoked or return true
            return notRevoked && !tag.revoked;
        })
    );

    // return tags as is
    if (pureTags) {
        return filteredTags;
    }

    return filteredTags.map(tag => {
        return {
            id: tag.id,
            rfid: tag.rfid,
            expiryDate: tag.expiryDate,
            revoked: tag.revoked,
            enabled: tag.enabled
        }
    });
}
```

Please note, after running the code in this update or in the original question, I see the debugger hitting the `getDrivers()` method, then the (HTTP) response is sent to the client, and only after 0.5~1s I see the `getDrivers()` method returning and proceeding to the next method.

Comment: the same problem I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @evgenifotia yup, know about and tried the `Promise.all`. Same result, I opted to show only the filter part to be more concise. Will post the `Promise.all` as an update to address any questions or suggestions made for it.

Comment: You can't just use an `async` function as a callback to something that won't do anything useful with the promise the `async` function returns. `filter` just checks the return to see if it's a truthy value -- **all** promise instances are truthy values. If you want to do all the async work in parallel, you can use `map` to build an array of promises and then `Promise.all` to wait for them all to settle. If you want to do them one after another, use a `for` or `for-of` loop and `push` to your result array.

Comment: FWIW, something along these lines: https://pastebin.com/JvE21Yja

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for your advice. I wanted to use `map` however, I felt this will slow down performance due to having to call `getDrivers()`, then `getTrucks()`, etc w/o checking if `drivers.length > 0`. I don't show that here as I modified it to check if I am getting results, but that was the original intention. Seems like I will need to make `3 x X` calls regardless which is what I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder or your example doing all in the `map` followed by `filter()` is a nifty solution, thank you!

Comment: @CybeX - You're welcome! You can (and yes, probably should) make the `if`s that check those more proactive: https://pastebin.com/YHJTTPFL Truth be told, I didn't read the code closely at all, just wanted to provide a sketch. :-)

Comment: On an unrelated note, doing a `.findAll()` on the database and filtering the entire result set on the client end seems enormously wasteful. Try to figure out a way to let the database filter most of these things.

Comment: On a second unrelated note, if your tags have a `revoked` property, it feels kind of weird to have a `notRevoked` function argument. Having `revoked = false` as the argument would feel more natural to me, especially since the other argument isn't called `notDisabled`, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your central problem is, as T.J. Chowder has commented, that you are trying to `.filter()` on something that is sometimes a boolean, and sometimes a promise.

You should do the mapping and the filtering in different steps. I tend to prefer the `.then()` syntax, so here's my approach:

```
const getAllTags = (pureTags = false, unused = true, enabled = true, notRevoked = false) => {
    return db.dbRfid.findAll()
        .then(allTags => allTags.map(tag => Promise.resolve(
            enabled === tag.enabled && notRevoked === !tag.revoked && Promise.all([
                tag.getDrivers(), tag.getTrucks(), tag.getUsers()
            ]).then(results => results.some(r => r.length))
        ).then(ok => ok ? tag : null)))
        .then(pendingTags => Promise.all(pendingTags))
        .then(resolvedTags => resolvedTags.filter(tag => tag))
        .then(filteredTags => filteredTags.map(tag => pureTags ? tag : {
            id: tag.id,
            rfid: tag.rfid,
            expiryDate: tag.expiryDate,
            revoked: tag.revoked,
            enabled: tag.enabled
        }));
};
```

The logic of this code:

- fetch tags from DB
  *produces `Promise<Tag[]>`, i.e. a promise for an array of tags*
- map each tag to a new promise that resolves either to the tag itself, or `null`, depending on a condition we figure out using `Promise.resolve()`, to account for the potentially<sup>(*)</sup> async nature of that check
  *produces `Promise<Promise<Tag|null>[]>`*
- wait for all those inner promises to resolve using `Promise.all()`
  *produces `<Promise<(Tag|null)[]>`*
- filter out the `null` values (i.e. tags we don't want)
  *produces `<Promise<Tag[]>`*
- map the tags to the overall result data structure we want, depending on `pureTags`
  *produces `<Promise<(Tag|object)[]>`*

<sup>(*)</sup> The `Promise.all()` is only invoked if the preconditions check out, due to short circuiting. If not, it's simply a `Promise.resolve(false)`, which resolves to `false` immediately. In the other case it's going to be `Promise.resolve(<Promise<Boolean>)`, which works exactly the same way as `Promise.resolve(Boolean)`. This way we can unify the synchronous and the asynchronous test.

In the subsequent `.then()` we can decide whether to return the `tag` - or `null`, to indicate that this tag failed the filter conditions. The `null` values are then picked out by `resolvedTags.filter(tag => tag)`.

Note that your code serializes the three async checks (`getDrivers`, `getTrucks`, `getUsers`) because each is awaited before the next is started. Using `Promise.all()` lets them run in parallel, which is one of the reasons why I dislike using `async`/`await` for everything.

I leave rewriting this into `async`/`await` style as an exercise.

Comment: thanks for the exercise (think I already did it...almost ;) )